# jDocument class under /libraries/joomla/document/json ignored

Tags: json, joomla

On a site I'm working on I've added /public_html/libraries/joomla/document/json from my installation because it wasn't there. The site runs on 1.5 and locally I'm using Joomla 2.5

My url has the added `&format=json` but can see that the response headers are text/html. Maybe the file from 2.5 is incompatible with 1.5. It has the following content:

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;
class JDocumentJSON extends JDocument
{
    protected $_name = 'joomla';
    public function __construct($options = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->_mime = 'application/json';
        $this->_type = 'json';
    }
    public function render($cache = false, $params = array())
    {
        JResponse::allowCache(false);
        JResponse::setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $this->getName() . '.json"', true);

        parent::render();

        return $this->getBuffer();
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }
    public function setName($name = 'joomla')
    {
        $this->_name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you just pulled some file from 2.5 and stuck it in 1.5? No that is not going to work.

Comment: @Elin Thank you for eliminating what doesn't work. On an unrelated subject; do you know the API reference to 1.5? It doesn't seem to be on the Joomla site or they're hiding it pretty good.

Comment: @Elin Found it: http://docs.joomla.org/Framework/1.5 redirected to another page that's also been deleted. I feel sorry for all those people that took the time to write and translate these documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the raw.php of the 1.5 version I noticed only little differences:

render doesn't have a public modifier

And maybe more important in 1.5 the parent::render is called first, so the code now looks like:

```
<?php
/**
* @version      $Id: json.php 14401 2010-01-26 14:10:00Z louis $
* @package      Joomla.Framework
* @subpackage   Document
* @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
* @license      GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
* Joomla! is free software. This version may have been modified pursuant
* to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
* is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
* other free or open source software licenses.
* See COPYRIGHT.php for copyright notices and details.
*/

// Check to ensure this file is within the rest of the framework
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die();

/**
 * DocumentJSON class, provides an easy interface to parse and display json output
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Framework
 * @subpackage  Document
 * @since       1.5
 */

class JDocumentJSON extends JDocument
{

    /**
     * Class constructore
     *
     * @access protected
     * @param   array   $options Associative array of options
     */
    protected $_name = 'joomla';
    function __construct($options = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->_mime = 'application/json';
        $this->_type = 'json';
    }

    /**
     * Render the document.
     *
     * @access public
     * @param boolean   $cache      If true, cache the output
     * @param array     $params     Associative array of attributes
     * @return  The rendered data
     */
    function render( $cache = false, $params = array())
    {
        parent::render();
        JResponse::allowCache(false);
        JResponse::setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $this->getName() . '.json"', true);
        return $this->getBuffer();
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }
    public function setName($name = 'joomla')
    {
        $this->_name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The headers are set correctly now